# Como iterar un diccionario en Plantilla Django?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

tengo el siguiente diccionario:

```
ordenes = [{u'enviadas': 21, u'fecha': u'2019-07-1'}, 
 {u'enviadas': 15, u'fecha': u'2019-07-2'}, 
 {u'enviadas': 29, u'fecha': u'2019-07-3'}, 
 {u'enviadas': 26, u'fecha': u'2019-07-4'}, 
 {u'enviadas': 12, u'fecha': u'2019-07-5'}, 
 {u'enviadas': 0, u'fecha': u'2019-07-6'}, 
 {u'enviadas': 0, u'fecha': u'2019-07-7'}, 
 {u'enviadas': 19, u'fecha': u'2019-07-8'}]
```

Del diccionario que muestro arriba necesito iterarlo en la Plantilla Django, necesito poner enviadas en una columna y fecha en otra columna de la tabla, estoy realizando el proceso con el siguiente código pero no obtengo resultados positivos, alguna ayuda?

```
{% for key,value in ordenes.items %} 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{img.key}}
                </td>

                <td>
                   {{img.value}}
                </td>
            </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería algo así.

```
{% for item in ordenes%}
    <td>{{ item.enviadas }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.fecha }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```